# How would I view last recorded data of each day of current week?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to view the last recorded data but I can't figure out the query.

This is my query for now. it returns all the data of this week:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, t.date) AS date, kwh AS kwh, time
FROM tbl_totalEnergy t
WHERE t.date > = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE() -1), 0)
```

Comment: Can you give a sample row of your data set, please?

Comment: Based on what I understand so far you are after SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [TABLE] ORDER BY [YourDateColumn] DESC

Comment: @BartoszX it will only show one data. I need to show the last recorded data of each day of the current week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below (I assume Date columnn is of type Date)

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.DATE ORDER BY t.time DESC) RNO
, kwh as kwh, t.time 
FROM tbl_totalEnergy t
WHERE t.date > = DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0, GETDATE() -1 ),0) 
)A 
WHERE RNO=1
```

Comment: Now check the updated answer, I removed brackets @hikarisakunami

Comment: it doesn't display the data of the last recorded time :(

Comment: I think you are storing Time on Time column. It could be easy for us if you give your table info fully. However I have changed Order by in Row Number. Give it a try once.. @hikarisakunami

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can query as below:

```
Select * from (
   SELECT DATENAME(dw,t.date) as date, kwh as kwh, time,
          RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by Year(t.date), DatePart(wk,t.date), Day(t.date) order by t.date desc)
                FROM tbl_totalEnergy t
  ) a
  Where a.RowN = 1
  and a.[date] between getdate() and dateadd(dd,-7,getdate())
```

Comment: it has error. it says Week is not a recognized built-in function name

Answer (score 0):

The time is in a separate column, so:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, t.date) as date, kwh as kwh, time
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATENAME(dw, t.date) ORDER BY t.date DESC, t.time DESC) as seqnum
      FROM tbl_totalEnergy t
      WHERE t.date >= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, GETDATE() -1 ), 0) 
    ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: it doesn't display the data of the last recorded time :(

Comment: @hikarisakunami . . . I didn't realize that `time` was in a separate column.  I updated the answer.